# No internet when NOT on VPN

Tags: release-hera, wifi, ethernet, openvpn

I'm a linux newbie and I've just installed elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera on dual boot with Win10. After the install everything was running good, I installed the protonvpn-cli v1.0.0.1 with no problem. After a reboot, the only way I can access the internet is by connecting the VPN, otherwise it just wouldn't connect. I've tried Wifi, ethernet, nothing works. Any ideas on what the issue might be? My computer is a Latitude E7250

Answer (score 0):

You can remove and disable the package by running:

```
sudo apt remove --purge protonvpn-cli
```